# Multiple criteria search button with regex(patterns)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

When I run the following code it works just fine. The only problem is that when the first textbox pattern is respected the datagridview shows data and no error message even though the other textbox, for example middle name, has numbers in it.
Exemple of patterns :

```
!Regex.Match(FirstNameTextBox.Text, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success && !Regex.Match(FirstNameTextBox.Text, "^[a-z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success
```

I'm just stuck at the moment>

```
if (FirstNameTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(FirstNameTextBox.Text, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success && !Regex.Match(FirstNameTextBox.Text, "^[a-z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
            {
                // first name was incorrect
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid First name Format", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                FirstNameTextBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String req = "Select * from Users where FirstName Like '" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "%' and SecondName Like '" + SecondNameTextBox.Text + "%' and MiddleName Like '" + MiddleNameTextBox.Text + "%' and DNI Like '" + DNITextBox.Text + "%' and Email Like '" + EmailTextBox.Text + "%' and PhoneNumber Like '" + PhoneNumberTextBox.Text + "%'";

                cn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                UsersGrd.DataSource = dt;
                cn.Close();

            }

        }
        else if (SecondNameTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(SecondNameTextBox.Text, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success && !Regex.Match(SecondNameTextBox.Text, "^[a-z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
            {
                // second name was incorrect
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Format", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                FirstNameTextBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String req = "Select * from Users where FirstName Like '" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "%' and SecondName Like '" + SecondNameTextBox.Text + "%' and MiddleName Like '" + MiddleNameTextBox.Text + "%' and DNI Like '" + DNITextBox.Text + "%' and Email Like '" + EmailTextBox.Text + "%' and PhoneNumber Like '" + PhoneNumberTextBox.Text + "%'";

                cn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                UsersGrd.DataSource = dt;
                cn.Close();

            }
        }

        else if (EmailTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(EmailTextBox.Text, "^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$").Success)
            {
                // second name was incorrect
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email Format", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                FirstNameTextBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String req = "Select * from Users where FirstName Like '" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "%' and SecondName Like '" + SecondNameTextBox.Text + "%' and MiddleName Like '" + MiddleNameTextBox.Text + "%' and DNI Like '" + DNITextBox.Text + "%' and Email Like '" + EmailTextBox.Text + "%' and PhoneNumber Like '" + PhoneNumberTextBox.Text + "%'";

                cn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                UsersGrd.DataSource = dt;
                cn.Close();

            }
        }
        else if (PhoneNumberTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(PhoneNumberTextBox.Text, "^[0-9]*$").Success)
            {
                // second name was incorrect
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Phone number Format", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                FirstNameTextBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String req = "Select * from Users where FirstName Like '" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "%' and SecondName Like '" + SecondNameTextBox.Text + "%' and MiddleName Like '" + MiddleNameTextBox.Text + "%' and DNI Like '" + DNITextBox.Text + "%' and Email Like '" + EmailTextBox.Text + "%' and PhoneNumber Like '" + PhoneNumberTextBox.Text + "%'";

                cn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                UsersGrd.DataSource = dt;
                cn.Close();

            }
        }
        else if (MiddleNameTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(MiddleNameTextBox.Text, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
            {
                // second name was incorrect
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Middle name Format", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                FirstNameTextBox.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                String req = "Select * from Users where FirstName Like '" + FirstNameTextBox.Text + "%' and SecondName Like '" + SecondNameTextBox.Text + "%' and MiddleName Like '" + MiddleNameTextBox.Text + "%' and DNI Like '" + DNITextBox.Text + "%' and Email Like '" + EmailTextBox.Text + "%' and PhoneNumber Like '" + PhoneNumberTextBox.Text + "%'";

                cn.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(req, cn);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                UsersGrd.DataSource = dt;
                cn.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: **Security hazard!** This query is an open door for [SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/) attacks.